# Position Indicator with respect to the selected item in list view in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I have a Row with a list view and an Indicator view. I would like to animate the indicator view with respect to the selected item in the list.

If I select an item in the list view, the Indicator view should move to the respective position as in the given Image.[image]

Please suggest something to make this UI.

sample code is given below.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: 6,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13),
            child: Text('Item$index'),
          ),
        ),
        Stack(
          children: [
            SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/images/scale_img.svg',
            ),
            Positioned(
              right: 26,
              top: 310,
              child:Container(
                width: 40,
                height: 4,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    gradient: const LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        colors: [
                          Color(0xffFF7EB4),
                          Color(0xffAA16CF),
                        ]),
                    boxShadow: const [
                      BoxShadow(
                        blurRadius: 10,
                        spreadRadius: -1,
                        offset: Offset(0, 4),
                        color:   Color(0xffAA16CF),
                      )
                    ]),
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: it would be nice if you include your sample code

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh Please check the sample code

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Indicator Animation Example'),
        ),
        body: IndicatorListView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class IndicatorListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<IndicatorListView> createState() => _IndicatorListViewState();
}

class _IndicatorListViewState extends State<IndicatorListView> {
  int selectedIndex = -1;
  int itemCount = 50;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        ListView.builder(
          itemCount: itemCount,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text('Item $index'),
              selected: index == selectedIndex,
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  selectedIndex = index;
                });
              },
            );
          },
        ),
        AnimatedPositioned(
          top: selectedIndex * (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / itemCount),
          right: 0,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / itemCount,
            width: 16,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.My updated answer is given below.

Answer (score 0):

We can find the position of the selected item using the RenderBox.
using this position we can move the indicator to the respective position.

Sample code is as follows.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Indicator Animation Example'),
        ),
        body: IndicatorListView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class IndicatorListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<IndicatorListView> createState() => _IndicatorListViewState();
}

class _IndicatorListViewState extends State<IndicatorListView> {
  int selectedIndex = -1;
  int itemCount = 10;
  List<GlobalKey> _keys = [];
  Offset? _selectedOffset;
   
  @override
  void initState() {
    _keys = List<GlobalKey>.generate(itemCount, (index) => GlobalKey());
    
    super.initState();
  }
  


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        ListView.builder(
          itemCount: itemCount,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              key: _keys[index],
              title: Text('Item $index'),
              selected: index == selectedIndex,
              onTap: () {
                var renderBox = _keys[index].currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
                _selectedOffset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
                setState(() {
                  selectedIndex = index;
                });
              },
            );
          },
        ),
        AnimatedPositioned(
          top: (_selectedOffset?.dy??0) - 35,
          right: 0,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          child: Container(
            height: 5,
            width: 29,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```